# C# - Is the size of a file have an influence on the write speed?

Tags: c#, performance, logging, size, streamwriter

I have a LogFile which log at a rhythm of (10MB/Hours) and this program need to run for the next 10+ Years. I need to decided at which size I create a new log file !

I have compare the time to write in a 10KB File with the time for a 1GB+ file and the time are almost the same.

Is the size of a file have an influence on the write speed,
is it recommended to keep the size of a log file pretty small ?

My C# Logging Function :

```
//LOGGING FUNCTION
public static void Log(string LogInfo)
{
    //FILE SIZE LIMITATION 50 000 000 Bytes, 50MB
    MaximumFileSize = 50000000
    long FileSize = 0;

    if (File.Exists("../Log/EventLog.txt"))
    {
        FileSize = new System.IO.FileInfo("../Log/EventLog.txt").Length;
    }
    if (File.Exists("../Log/EventLog.txt") && (FileSize > MaximumFileSize)) NewLog();

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("../Log/")) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("../Log/");

    using (StreamWriter s = File.AppendText("../Log/EventLog.txt"))
    {
        s.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -- " + LofInfo);
        s.Close();
    }
}

//FUNCTION TO ARCHIVE LOG
public static void NewLog()
{

    if (File.Exists("../Log/EventLog.txt"))
    {
        File.Move("../Log/EventLog.txt", "../Log/EventLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss") + ".txt");
    }

}
```

Comment: This will only impact the RAM as in 10 years you will need 10MB*24h*365days*10years/1024MB = 855GB, that's a lot of RAM

or 1GB if your limit is 1GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had an application that logs small binary files (a couple of KB). We've written approximately 10 times as much data per day and even though the files have been really small even an old laptop HDD from 2000 has been able to keep up without any problem. This probably answers your main question.

However: When we are moving GBs of these files the transfer speed is horribly slow. SSDs are relatively better than HDDs but still very slow (less than 1MB/s).

On a fragmented HDD small files may fit in small free disk spaces all over the disk while a large file is more likely to be put in one large chunk. Since the HDD is likely to spin one revolution each time it doesn't read a sequential stream of data the transfer speed will be impacted.

The best size per file probably varies by disk but daily or weekly log (10-70 MB) files seems like a good trade off between ease of sending the files and transfer speed when you need to copy a year of log files.

Comment: Erik Ovegard - Thanks a lot, that was exactly the kind of answer i wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Also think about how you will use those log files. They are typically opened in Notepad or similar, which takes a noticeably more time as the file gets larger. Good luck opening a 1GB file in something like that. I would stick to more, like, 10 megabytes per file (even that won't be instantaneous to open). It's trivial to come up with a sorted-filename-naming logic to keep files easy to relate to each other if need be.

Even better, create new log files as dates change (and incorporate yyyy-mm-dd formatting in filenames for better sorting). For comparison, take a look at options that IIS-logging offers related to rotating log files. After all, it's much easier to determine which log file the **current** log-entry needs to go to (if daily/hourly schema, file names will be deterministic) then it will be to determine the current **size** of the **current** log file (also think simultaneous access by multiple threads/app-instances). In other words, it's much easier to use current-system-time to determine the target log file. If you anticipate chatty logs, then go hourly; otherwise daily scheme will probably be enough. They'll be of various sizes, but that's perhaps ok (you won't be able to achieve exact-byte equivalency even if you go fixed-size).

Otherwise, you'll have to write code just to read those same files, in which case that begs the question of: why not use database to store that log information, as it would be easier to use to present in some future viewer.

Comment: My suggestion was primarily for rotating files based on system-time (as opposed to file-size); logging to a database was just an honorable mention. You can even come up with a folder-naming scheme; e.g. `/yyyy/mm/dd/hh-service1.txt`

Comment: I would just stay away from measuring file size: if multiple threads or app-instances are logging at the same time, you'll have big concurrency problem and likely undesired file-size issues. You cannot control the amount of text logged, therefore you will not be able to easily control file-size accurately (unless you're adding blank spaces to fill up); it's just unnecessary logging logic (measure file, measure what's about to be added, add there or pad existing file, then start new file, what if another thread already created new file, what if the newly created file already got filled up?

Comment: 1. build full-path based on current time; 2. create dir+file if it's not there; 3. append